# Is product of rotation map topologically transitive?

Tags: dynamical-systems, chaos-theory

Define rotation map on $f:S^{1}\rightarrow S^{1}$ such that $\theta \rightarrow \theta +2\pi\alpha, $  where $\alpha$ is some fixed irrational. Is $f\times f$ topologically transitive?

A function $f:X\rightarrow X$ where $(X, d) $ is a metric space,  is said to be topologically transitive if for every pair of non-empty disjoint open sets $U$ and $V$ of $X$,  there exist some natural number $n$ such that $f^{n} (U) \cap V$ is non empty.

Comment: $f$ is topologically transitive.  I am trying to show what will happen to direct product.  If direct product is not topologically transitive then we need to find such open sets. What will be that?

Comment: That is not true for $\alpha$ rational.

Comment: Some definitions for topologically transitive sets do not assume that $U$ and $V$ are disjoint.  Just distinct.

Comment: I edited. Please check,  $\alpha $ is irrational.  It is transitive as,  orbit is dense and $S^{1} $ is thick space.  What will happen to its direct product to itself?

Comment: Any good reference of proof saying torus have have rational slope?

Answer (score 4):

$f\times f$ is not topologically transitive: the slope on the torus is rational and so all orbits of $f\times f$ are contained in a closed curve (a geodesic in the flat metric), which thus is not dense.

Comment: Weak mixing imply transitivity but converse need not true.. So even if it is not weak mixing we can not say it is transitive

Comment: How does your comment relate to my complete answer?

Answer (score 0):

Irrational rotation on $S^1$ is an isometry and hence not weak mixing. That means $f \times f$ is not transitive.